# Slightly Different Interfaces

Tags: design-patterns, c++, object-oriented-design

I am creating a class which has an instance variable that has many different implementations, but the problem is that all of the implementations have a slightly different interface.

Example:

```
class GameObject {
    virtual Transform * getTransform() = 0;
};

class Transform {
    virtual void setPosition() = 0;
    virtual Model getModel() = 0;
    virtual void refreshModel() = 0;
    virtual void Draw() = 0;
};

// This Class has a .cpp
class TransformImpl : public Transform {
    virtual void setPosition();
    Model getModel();
    void refreshModel();
    void Draw();
};

// This Class has a .cpp
class InstancedTransformImpl : public Transform {
    void setPosition(int instance);
    std::vector<Model> getModels(); // notice the difference in the interface
    void refreshModel();
    void Draw();
};
```

The point I want to make is that I only want one `GameObject` class thus I want my `geTransform()` method have a return type of class `Transform`. The problem I'm having is that since `TransformImpl` and `InstancedTrasformImpl` have slightly different interfaces I can't have `getTransform()` to return a `Transform` and instead I need to implement `GameObject` twice with lots of duplicated code.

Is there a good solution to implement `GameObject` once?

Or would it be better to have multiple `GameObject` implementations each having there respective `Transform`Impl's with a more lenient interface?

Comment: Could you standardize on `std::vector<Model> getModels()` for both interfaces? `Model getModel()` coiuld be represented as a vector with one element.

Comment: this is just a simple example, there are more methods. Basically one `class` contains many instances of transform and the other `class` contains only one instance. I'll update

Comment: can you make `Model` and `std::vector<Model>` a template parameter in interface/implementatoin ?

Comment: @k3b I thought the same, but what to do with `setPosition()`?

Comment: setPosition is modell specific so you have to implement two model-specific classes. the interface can still be generic.

Comment: Isn't your Transform abstraction almost like a component in the [Composite pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite/cpp/1)? TransformImpl is a leaf node and InstancedTransformImpl is a composite (it has multiple models and a setPosition with an index)? Maybe? If so, I can do up an answer that is more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use two (or more) implementation classes interchangeably, then those implementation classes *must* implement the same interface. This is especially important if the selection which implementation class you interact with is decided at runtime.

If the difference between the interfaces is that one class allows you access to N instances of something and the other to just 1, then the common interface should give you access to N instances.
Allowing access to a more restricted number can be modeled as a special case of the situation with access to an unrestricted number.

In this case, the interface should be

```
class Transform {
    virtual void setPosition(int instance) = 0;
    virtual std::vector<Model> getModel() = 0;
    virtual void refreshModel() = 0;
    virtual void Draw() = 0;
};
```

The `TransformImpl` class can then always return a vector with 1 element from `getModel` and either ignore the `instance` parameter to `setPosition` or report an error if that parameter has a value other than 0 or 1 (depending on where you start counting).

Comment: Isn't this bad practice though? It doesn't seem right to be sending over a parameter which isn't really used and for it to be returning a vector of only size one

Comment: @archimede, it is only a bad practice if there is no good reason for it.  In your case, the alternative is a massive duplication of code, which is a much bigger bad practice.

Comment: You could apply Segration of Interface principle too. But It would make the code a little bit more complex. So far, Bart's answer is a fairly good solution. It will allow you to treat all `Transform` implementations in the very same way. Anyways, I got the feeling that `Transform` interface is failing as abstraction. I think the design misses a cross-cutting concept that has led you to segment the implementations in such a way that some of them will accomplish with the interface and others will do just 50%.

Answer (score 2):

How about the adapter pattern?
Create multiple types of GameObject Implementations and work with all of them through an adapter that abstracts their differences:
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter

Comment: What if I have an `InstancedTransfom` interface. Both my `InstancedTransformImpl` and `TransformImpl` implement `InstancedTransform` but what if I make a `TransformImpl` adapter which always grabs the  0th element. But if I do this how can I hide the `InstancedTransform` methods from the client using `TransformImpl`. To avoid this would I need to have an instance of `InstancedTransform`

Comment: But if I have an instance of `InstancedTransform` in `TransformImpl` then it'll screw up `GameObject`'s interface for `getTransform()`

Comment: The adapter pattern reveals only what you want it to reveal. You can even create a factory that produces adapters, each one relating to the right object and wrapping it in an appropriate way.